# How do I redirect the user to a new page when using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

In my program when sending a mail using PHPMailer, I'd like an alert box to appear and redirect the user to my index page.

However it will only does redirect to the index page and it does not show the alert box. However, when I remove header redirection it shows the alert box and redirects the user to the same page as the PHP script.

Where would I write the PHPMailer code or show sever message?

**PHP**

```
   <?php 
//date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['email'])&& isset($_POST['message']))
{ 

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
    }
    else
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                          // Passing `true` enables exceptions

        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP(true);                                  // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.Gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'luckynath4@gmail.com';             // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'zedlucky@lucky';                   // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to,25,587-tls,465-ssl.
        //$mail->AddCC($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
        $mail->addAddress("luckynath4@gmail.com","PROREX");    // Add a recipient


        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = "PROREX CONTACT";
        $mail->Body = "<h3>".$_POST['message']."</h3>";

         if( $mail->send())
         {
             //echo "email was send";
             echo '<script language="javascript">';
             echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
             echo '</script>';
             header("location: index.php");

             exit();
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
         }   


    }   
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="card">
     <form action="" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">your name</label>
     <div class="input-group">
    <div class=" input-group-addon bg-light"><i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i></div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"placeholder="User name" required />
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class=" input-group-addon bg-light"><i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey- text"></i></div>
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Email Adress"  required> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon bg-light"><i class="fa fa-pencil text-grey"></i>
    </div>
   <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" required> 
  </textarea>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn 
  unique">Send<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-2"></i></button>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: To use PHP `header` you cannot send any output before, so get rid of that alert script

Comment: remove the echo before the header.

Comment: In the future, please only use those tags which directly relate your question/code.

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to store the send status in the session, issue the redirect, then display the status (read from the session) when you render the destination page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a PHPMailer issue, your code is instantly redirecting the user to your index page, as a result, the alert is not being able to display.

What you are looking for is a timed redirection. This can be done through the client side or by using the `header` function as you have done.

Change,

```
header("location: index.php");
```

To,

```
header("Refresh:3; url=index.php");
```

Notice the change, the `3` defines the countdown time before the redirection takes place.

**Reading Material**

[`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114)

Comment: it work but, between completion of 3 sec it show server message,i don't want to show server message.

Comment: i mean it show this type of message after sending mail,after clicking ok button of alert box.

Comment: 2018-03-03 05:47:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN, tls has to be start and may more long list of message.